# extra .git directory exists in package

Tags: git, github, composer-php, packagist

i create a package in packagist.org related to a github repository.
After install this package in a new project, this package includes a .git directory which contains the information of the related github repository.

But this .git directory does not exists in other familiar package, like guzzle/guzzle.

when i run `composer remove package/package`, it just fails. Because the mod of some files in .git is 111, which could not be removed by any user.

how can i get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

the key point is minimum-stability version. It seems that when the repository has NOT a release version, this situation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
$ rm -rf vendor/package/package
```

to delete the package, and if necessary, retry with sudo

```
$ sudo rm -rf vendor/package/package
```

Then remove the package from `composer.json` by running

```
$ composer remove package/package
```

As pointed out in the other answer, if the package hasn't been tagged yet, then it will be installed from source, and the only thing you can do to avoid the problems you have indicated is this:

- tag the package `package/package` and require a tagged version
- do not modify the content of `vendor` manually, and specifically, do not modify any content in `vendor/package/package`